# How Can I Coding a Trigger for Select Option?

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, jquery-select2, checkout

I am working on the Woocommerce checkout page. With jQuery, if the checkbox is checked, I move the data to the invoice form on the delivery form.
Shipping First Name vs. no problem for it. However, the problem occurs while moving shipping_city (select option). I can't see this without refreshing the page.
I have a trigger printer for this but it doesn't work.

On the checkout page, "Send to a different address?" There is a checkbox like (default). After clicking this checkbox, a form opens. In this form name, surname etc. there is information. All of these are available on woocommerce by default.
All I do is above. So all the code is there. What am I trying to do?
I am filling out the newly opened form. After checking the checkbox, I send it to the above form.
What is the problem ? Unable to send billing_city without reloading the page. It does not seem instant.

Update: As far as I can see it uses the Woocommerce select2 library. I've reviewed this library but still haven't been able to write a trigger for the change in billing_city.
HTML Code Image: https://i.ibb.co/1fgD1By/a023046.png

My code is below:

```
function add_checkout_script() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).on('change', '#copy_to_billing', function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            //For example, momentarily, the data in shipping_first_name is transferred to billing_first_name.
            jQuery("[name='billing_first_name']").val(jQuery("[name='shipping_first_name']").val());
            
            //However, here the data is transferred after the page is loaded. This is a list of options. I want to transfer the page instantly without refreshing it.
            jQuery("[name='billing_city']").filter(":selected").val(jQuery("[name='shipping_city']").filter(":selected").val());
   
        }
    });
           
    </script>
<input id="copy_to_billing" type ="checkbox" name="copy_to_billing" 
value ="1" class="copy_billing woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox"><span><?php esc_html_e( ' Send', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
<?php       
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'add_checkout_script' );
```

Comment: First in WooCommerce, checkout billing city is a text input field by default. So it seems that you have customized this field and you should provide in your question the related code. Now what does mean *"Coding a Trigger for Select Option"* or *"I have a trigger printer for this…"*? Try to make things clear and better explain what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Please again look.